# Can you explan this weird "updating" of np.array content inside a deque?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deque

this code seems to "update" the content inside a deque ? e.g.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

buffer = deque()
load = np.array([1])

for loop in range(5):     
    print(list(buffer))  
    print("   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...")
    load[0] = loop
    print(list(buffer))              
    print("   >>>>> buffer.append ...")
    buffer.append([loop, load])
```

*output =*

```
[]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([0])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([1])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([1])], [1, array([1])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([2])], [1, array([2])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([2])], [1, array([2])], [2, array([2])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([3])], [1, array([3])], [2, array([3])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([3])], [1, array([3])], [2, array([3])], [3, array([3])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([4])], [1, array([4])], [2, array([4])], [3, array([4])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
```

... as you can see, the array content inside the deque is updated when the array is assigned new value ?

Comment: You get the same problem if you make a list, `alist = [[0]]*4`, and try to modify one element `alist[0][0]=2`.

Comment: Interesting ... and yes, that too is counter-intuitive (to me).

Comment: .... using instead   alist = [[0,0,0,0]]  ... fixes this.   But makes "[[0]]*4" look like a dangerous way to do things ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `load` object in your code, each item of your deque refers to this same and only one. If you want them to be different, create a new one in each loop:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import deque

buffer = deque()


for loop in range(5):     
    print(list(buffer))  
    print("   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...")
    load = np.array([loop])
    print(list(buffer))              
    print("   >>>>> buffer.append ...")
    buffer.append([loop, load])
```

Output:

```
[]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([0])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([0])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])], [2, array([2])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])], [2, array([2])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])], [2, array([2])], [3, array([3])]]
   >>>>> load[0] = loop # .... ...
[[0, array([0])], [1, array([1])], [2, array([2])], [3, array([3])]]
   >>>>> buffer.append ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix... below 2nd answer explains.. "Every element you append to the buffer keeps pointing at the same np.array, initially named load." ... seems to be something to be very careful of !

Comment: I also found ".copy()" to fix it ...  e.g.  buffer.append([loop, load, load.copy()])

Answer (score 0):

The `deque` is holding a [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) to the single list. Every element you append to the `buffer` keeps pointing at the same `np.array`, initially named `load`.